# Do anyone know how to fetch a column on database in sqllite to an array?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have arrays in python like:

```
Temperature = ([34, 23.4, 25.5, 16.7])
Humidity = ([89, 93, 78, 59, 61)]
```

I have store them in SQLlite as .db file

```
Temperature  Humidity
34            89
23.4          93
25.5          78
25.5          59
16.7          61
```

Now I want to take the data back from my storage. Do anyone knows how to fetch a column back to an array.

[image: Database.db]

Comment: If you are using SQLite - then sqlite3 module for python is the usual way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if you're using SQLite or MySQL, however the approach will be the same, if not very similar.

First thing you need to do is establish a connection with your database in python. If you're using mySQL you will need to import a library. Once the connection is established you will need to set up a cursor that will enable you to use database functions.

```
#This is for a mySQL database
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='#Your hose name goes here',
                               user='#your user name goes here',
                               password='#your password goes here',
                               db='#name of your db goes here')

#This cursor enables database functions
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('USE #enter database name here;')
cur.execute('SELECT Temperature FROM #insert name of database here;')

#To access the column we will store the data from the Temperature column into the  
#temperature var

temperature=cur.fetchall()

#Create an empty array 
temp_data=[]

#The for loop will be used to iterate through the data in the Temperature column
#and store it in the array
for data in temperature:
    temp_data.append(data)
```

If you are using SQLite you will need a differnt library to connect to your db. You will simply connect to your database like so:

```
import sqlite3
conn= sqlite3.connect('#name of your file.db')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it works nicely. Currently, I store the humidity in the database but somehow. It does not show as the text like Temperature value but the binary BLOB...Then when I collect data back. instead of the number, I got something like: (b'Z\x00\x00\x00',), (b'\\\x00\x00\x00',),....

Comment: hmmm, I don't fully understand what you're saying. So the code works for the temperature column, but not the humidity column?

Comment: At the end of the temperature for loop add "conn.commit()". This ends the current query you are doing in the database, that way one query won't interfere with the other.

Comment: Glad to hear! If my answered helped do you mind accepting it as the answer/up voting it?